# ExpandableListView, how to set the child height?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to set the **ExpandableListView** item (`ViewGroup`) height. Can it be set via xml (I don't need the divider height):

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

or it should be used this method, by manipulating the ***convertView***:

```
    @Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                         ViewGroup parent) { ... }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView child views can be different heights, so we don't set a one-size-fits all height in the ListView's xml.  Rather you can set a specific height in each of the different convertView xml's that you are inflating.

Comment: Thank you, I've used: "convertView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);" instead of "convertView.setMinimumHeight(40);".

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set the height of the group row item in the listview?  Also the `ViewGroup` would be your `ExpandableListView` and all of its groups and group children row items.

Or are you asking to set the height of the child items in the expandable list view?

The group item and its children in the listview are the same as any other listview row item.
You can just simply provide fixed height in row layout XML:

`android:layout_height="25dp"`

Or you could use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old, but someone may be useful. As others said, height is not strict value (it changes according to its content). If you want to generally make more space between items (whether it is group or child), you can set padding to corresponding layouts.

This can be done either in XML layout or programmatically in list adapter.